# filtering tweets based on two condition twitter API

Tags: java, search, twitter, filter, twitter4j

I have filtered tweets based on location using

> q.location(bbox);

If i have further check whether these tweets have set of keywords I used

> q.track("game")

My tweets either have the location or the words not both the conditions are met.
Are my statements correct? Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if you are using the streaming api, this is the expected behaviour - from the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/filter) (emphasis mine):

> The track, follow, and locations fields should be considered to be **combined with an OR operator**. track=foo&follow=1234 returns Tweets matching "foo" OR created by user 1234.

So in other words, you should get Tweets with the `bbox` location *or* containing the keyword `game`.

If you want to keep on using the streaming api, a possible solution may be to manually check received Tweets for the other condition, i.e. if the Tweet had the correct location then check the status text for the keyword etc...

Otherwise, consider using the [search api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) instead. See [`Twitter#search(Query)`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/SearchResource.html#search%28twitter4j.Query%29), for example:

```
final Query query = new Query("game");
query.setGeocode(...);
final QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
```

You should find that `Twitter#search(Query)` works more like the search on Twitter's website.

However, be aware that by using the search api, you may miss some Tweets:

> ...it's important to know that the Search API is focused on relevance and not completeness. This means that some Tweets and users may be missing from search results. If you want to match for completeness you should consider using a Streaming API instead.
>   ([source](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search))

Comment: to add up to @Jonathan's answer, if you decide to keep using the streaming API (which is what I recommend to do if you want real-time results and less burden): please be aware of the issue with twitter's API returning results outside of the bounding box you have defined: https://dev.twitter.com/issues/295. Means you should validate that the geotags are within the are you're interested in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the twitter4j API, but the twitter API allows this, you can test it with the [twitter advanced search test page](https://twitter.com/search-advanced).

Are you able to capture the get request that is issued?

Comment: yeah..I tried with twitter advanced search, I am getting the results but I want to do it in twitter4j API. :(

Comment: Are you able to capture the http request that is going out when you use twitter4j? If you can show that it's not generating the right URL for the twitter query, then you could file a twitter4j bug

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Streaming API in twitter4J? If so, I can recommend you to look at an example below:

```
   FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();

    String keywords[] = {"health", "politics"};

    double[][] loc={{-122.75,36.8},{-121.75,37.8}};

    fq.locations(loc);
    fq.track(keywords);        

    twitterStream.addListener(statusListener);
    twitterStream.filter(fq);
```

Comment: I did the same but getting results for either one of the query. Either the tweets are based on location or based on the keywords. But I want to get tweets based on the location and those tweets should have the keywords.

Comment: It should work. If you have a url in tweet content, check that url has one of the keywords. That means it is not necessary to have the keyword in the tweet content. It happens.